# Can I create a private co-op game in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'd like to create a co-op game that only my friends can join.  How is this done in Diablo 3?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the "Allow Quick join" option in the options -> social menu (bottom right corner). After that, people can only join your game if you invited. Friends you didn't invite will still be able to see **that** you're playing including the quest and information about your character in the friend list, but even they can't join you without your permission.

Answer (score 2):

Make a game, don't make it public but invite the friends to your party that you want to join by clicking the button beside their name on your friends list.